java.nio.file.Files.readString() is not available on android SDK 33
https://developer.android.com/build/jdks lists SDK 33 as supporting JDK 11 which has java.nio.Files.readString(). However, at runtime that method isn't available in Files. The method is used in a java library dependency to my app, and I didn't see any error that showed up when I built it. Is there a tool in Android studio to find these kinds of unimplemented APIs?
I compiled my app in Android studio targeting SDK 34 (which also doesn't have Files.readString()) with a minSDK of 33. There was no complaints that I could see from the build, but at runtime the readString method caused a no such method error.
I expected the error to be manifest during the build process.

Calls to methods that don't exist are common. Just consider the conditional code sections that are only executed if the device SDK version is in a specific range or other code parts that belong to special manufacturer APIs. Therefore the build process can not know which functions are available on a device and which not if the code belongs to an already compiled class. For that all compile time dependencies would have to be present.
